# Ion load download file from url and write to device gives 'null' file on some devices

Tags: android, download, android-ion, ion-koush

I am using https://github.com/koush/ion in my app to download files from urls and write them to Android devices.

Most of the time it works great but from the statistics there are around 15% of my users getting null file from the call back (onCompleted)

This is part of the code I use.

```
File d = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File f = new File(d, 'some_file_name');
Ion.with(this).load('some_url')
    .progress(new ProgressCallback() {
      ............
    })
    .write(f)
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<File>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, File file) {
              ....... file is null .....
        }
    });
```

Comment: For those that have a null file, could it be that they have a non-null `Exception e`?

Comment: Check the exception.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had forgotten to check the Android M permissions, the manifest permission were not enough.